# 2 columns with MUL as Key?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, key

I heard that if Key is MUL, the column is the first column of a nonunique index in which multiple occurrences of a given value are permitted within the column.

However, as pic attached, there are 2 columns with MUL as key. so what does it mean? Which one should be considered the first column?
Can an index included 1 columns?

Please help 
appreciate

[image: Click on the attached pic here]

Answer (score 0):

This means that the table has two non-unique indexes. `user_guid` is the first column in one of them, and `dog_guid` is the first column in the other.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` is usually more useful, since it will show the details of all the indexes.